# Powershell DSC 1.7 version parameter issue

Tags: powershell, azure, dsc

I am writing the PowerShell scripts to create network in Azure. I just checked the dsc version got updated from 1.5 to 1.6 and 1.7 in last two days. Due to which I am getting error within my scripts.

The dsc gets applied properly but in the management portal it errs out with the following message -

> Error enabling the DSC Extension: Cannot process argument
>   transformation on parameter 'ConfigurationFunction'. Cannot convert
>   the "System.Object[]" value of type "System.Object[]" to type
>   "System.Management.Automation.ConfigurationInfo".

The script is as follows -

```
Configuration DomainControllerVM
 {
     Node localhost 
     {
         Script DomainControllerVM
         {
             SetScript = {
                         $Pass = 'Test' 
                         $credpass = ConvertTo-SecureString -String $Pass -AsPlainText -Force
                         Install-WindowsFeature AD-Domain-Services -IncludeManagementTools
                         Install-ADDSForest -DomainName corp.contoso.com -DatabasePath "C:\NTDS" -SysvolPath "C:\SYSVOL" -LogPath "C:\Logs" -SafeModeAdministratorPassword $credpass -Force
                         #insert password twice when prompted
                         #Log to the machine using CORP\[Local administrator account name]
           Set-NetFirewallRule -DisplayName "File and Printer Sharing (Echo Request - ICMPv4-In)" -enabled True
           winrm quickconfig
           netsh advfirewall firewall set rule group="remote desktop" new enable=Yes
                         }

                TestScript = { 

                                  return $false 
                              }
                 GetScript = { <# This must return a hash table #> }          
         }
     }
 }
 Set-StrictMode -Off
 DomainControllerVM
 Start-DscConfiguration -Force -Wait -Verbose -Path .\DomainControllerVM
```

The log is as follows -

```
[2015-02-25T20:25:17] Executing DSC Extension
 [2015-02-25T20:25:17] File lock does not exist: begin processing
 [2015-02-25T20:25:17] Reading handler environment from C:\Packages\Plugins\Microsoft.Powershell.DSC\1.7.0.0\bin\..\HandlerEnvironment.json
 [2015-02-25T20:25:19] Reading handler settings from C:\Packages\Plugins\Microsoft.Powershell.DSC\1.7.0.0\RuntimeSettings\0.settings
 [2015-02-25T20:25:20] Applying DSC configuration:
 [2015-02-25T20:25:20]     Sequence Number:           0
 [2015-02-25T20:25:20]     Configuration Package URL:  https://~/windows-powershell-dsc/DomainControllerVM.ps1.zip
 [2015-02-25T20:25:20]     Configuration Container:   DomainControllerVM.ps1
 [2015-02-25T20:25:20]     Configuration Function:    DomainControllerVM (0 arguments)
 [2015-02-25T20:25:20]     Configuration Data URL:    
 [2015-02-25T20:25:20]     Certificate Thumbprint:    979C0B1CB40273DE0485B63AD45F59AA6E7DE2F6
 [2015-02-25T20:25:21] Using existing working directory: C:\Packages\Plugins\Microsoft.Powershell.DSC\1.7.0.0\bin\..\DSCWork\DomainControllerVM.ps1.0
 [2015-02-25T20:25:21] Applying DSC configuration DomainControllerVM.ps1\DomainControllerVM
 [2015-02-25T20:25:21] Writing handler status to C:\Packages\Plugins\Microsoft.Powershell.DSC\1.7.0.0\Status\0.status
 [2015-02-25T20:25:21] Looking for the definition of the configuration function.
 [2015-02-25T20:25:21] Executing script: C:\Packages\Plugins\Microsoft.Powershell.DSC\1.7.0.0\bin\..\DSCWork\DomainControllerVM.ps1.0\DomainControllerVM.ps1
 Perform operation 'Invoke CimMethod' with following parameters, ''methodName' = SendConfigurationApply,'className' = MSFT_DSCLocalConfigurationManager,'namespaceName' = root/Microsoft/Windows/DesiredStateConfiguration'.
 An LCM method call arrived from computer CHINEWN with user sid S-1-5-18.
 An LCM method call arrived from computer CHINEWN with user sid S-1-5-18.
 [CHINEWN]: LCM:  [ Start  Set      ]
 [CHINEWN]: LCM:  [ Start  Resource ]  [[Script]DomainControllerVM]
 [CHINEWN]: LCM:  [ Start  Test     ]  [[Script]DomainControllerVM]
 [CHINEWN]: LCM:  [ End    Test     ]  [[Script]DomainControllerVM]  in 1.5140 seconds.
 [CHINEWN]: LCM:  [ Start  Set      ]  [[Script]DomainControllerVM]
 [CHINEWN]:                            [[Script]DomainControllerVM] Performing the operation "Set-TargetResource" on target "Executing the SetScript with the user supplied credential".
 [CHINEWN]:                            [[Script]DomainControllerVM] Installation started...
 [CHINEWN]:                            [[Script]DomainControllerVM] Installation succeeded.
 Verification of prerequisites for Domain Controller promotion failed. The specified argument 'DataBasePath' was not recognized.

    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], CimException
     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Test.VerifyDcPromoCore.DCPromo.General.77,Microsoft.DirectoryServices.Deployment.PowerShell.Commands.InstallADDSForestCommand
     + PSComputerName        : localhost

 [CHINEWN]: LCM:  [ End    Set      ]  [[Script]DomainControllerVM]  in 24.1760 seconds.
 The PowerShell DSC resource MSFT_ScriptResource threw one or more non-terminating errors while running the Set-TargetResource functionality. These errors are logged to the ETW channel called Microsoft-Windows-DSC/Operational. Refer to this channel for more details.
     + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], CimException
     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NonTerminatingErrorFromProvider
     + PSComputerName        : localhost

 The SendConfigurationApply function did not succeed.
     + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (root/Microsoft/...gurationManager:String) [], CimException
     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MI RESULT 1
     + PSComputerName        : localhost

 Operation 'Invoke CimMethod' complete.
 Time taken for configuration job to complete is 35.692 seconds
 [2015-02-25T20:26:02] Preparing configuration arguments.
 [2015-02-25T20:26:02] Removing file lock
 C:\Packages\Plugins\Microsoft.Powershell.DSC\1.7.0.0\bin\DscExtensionHandler.ps1 : Error enabling the DSC Extension: Cannot process argument transformation on parameter 'ConfigurationFunction'. Cannot convert the "System.Object[]" value of type "System.Object[]" to type "System.Management.Automation.ConfigurationInfo".
 At line:7 char:2
 +  C:\Packages\Plugins\Microsoft.Powershell.DSC\1.7.0.0\bin\DscExtensio ...
 +  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorException
     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException,DscExtensionHandler.ps1

 [2015-02-25T20:26:02] Writing handler status to C:\Packages\Plugins\Microsoft.Powershell.DSC\1.7.0.0\Status\0.status
```

But the same script when execute from the target azure machine works fine.
Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use version 1.5 of the extension by running 'Set-AzureVMDscExtension -version 1.5'. Let me know if that fixes the issue

Answer (score 0):

Nana's workaround should work, but If you want to stay on the latest extension, Remove the following two lines below from your configuration script.  The extension does this for you.  Also, if you do add anything, other than the configuration definition, make sure you are redirecting the output to null.

Example redirect to null:
`Dir > $null`

**Lines to remove:**

```
 DomainControllerVM
 Start-DscConfiguration -Force -Wait -Verbose -Path .\DomainControllerVM
```

Disclaimer: I did this all on my phone from memory.  Please excuse any typos.